# Difference between Task Callbacks and OnCompleted()

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, multitasking

when I was playing with tasks on C#, I was wondering what's the difference between using GetAwaiter().OnCompleted() and callbacks

**Case 1 :** *task1.GetAwaiter().OnCompleted()*

```
Task task1 = new Task(() =>
            {
                //Do Work_1 here
            });

task1.GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(() =>
            {
                //Do something here where Work_1 Completed 
            });

task1.Start();
```

**Case 2 :** *CallBack*

```
await Task2(() =>
            {
                //CallBack                            
            });
private async Task Task2(Action callBack)
            {
               //do Work_2 here
               await Task.Run(callBack);
            }
```

I want to understand this and I think I'm missing something.

Comment: One observation I have is the MSDN remark on the `GetAwaiter()` method: [This method is intended for compiler user rather than use directly in code.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.getawaiter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before discussing the differences, I have to point out one thing: *you shoudn't use either of the two approaches*. `GetAwaiter()` is used internally by `await` and it can be useful in some specialized code, but you shouldn't use it in normal code. And continuation actions are exactly what `async`-`await` is trying to avoid.

If you want to have a continuation, either use `await`, or possibly `ContinueWith()`. Both have the advantage that they are composable: the callee just returns a `Task` and it's upon the caller to decide what to do it with it.

With that being said, there are some differences:

- In case 1, the continuation will run even when the `Task` fails.
- In case 1, the continuation will run on the current synchronization context, if any. In case 2, the continuation will always run on a thread pool thread.